# Обработка исключений, выгрузка значений переменных c#

Tags: c#, исключения

Для обработки исключений использую такой код

```
catch (Exception e)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("Error.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("U") +  
            " - " + e.Message + "\n");
        }
```

Вот только можно ли добавить выгрузку всех переменных, которые были заданы в приложении не перечисляя их?

Comment: Всех-всех? Даже локальных во всех методах всех классов? Или всё-таки только определённые нужные? Вообще, заведите модель (класс) для необходимой информации и сериализуйте (например, в json).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну и как бы вы это реализовали? И я имел ввиду конечно некоторое количество переменных, которые я бы создавал в отдельном классе

Comment: @polsok, ну поля класса можно через рефлексию получить или сделать какой-нибудь интерфейс с методов GetVariables и в каждом классе его реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Сомневаюсь, что такое можно сделать, так как понятие переменная стирается после компиляции кода. Т.е имени уже не существует названий переменных. Остаются только поля и свойства класса в виде метаданных.

Может быть какой-нибудь АОП фреймворк на такое способен. Например, [PostSharp](http://lsreg.ru/aspektno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie-na-c-s-ispolzovaniem-postsharp/).

Как вариант, вы можете все интересующие вас переменные держать в словаре и передавать его в метод, который будет работать со словарем и писать все в файл.

А вообще, как я понимаю, вы собираетесь писать лог и на мой взгляд, изобретаете велосипед, ведь есть `Log4net`, который достаточно гибкий.

**UPD**

В комментариях вы пишите, что затеяли такую авантюру так как не можете понять место возникновения ошибки.

Если проблема в том, что бы найти место, где программа отвалилась, то у вас 2 варианта:

1. Залогировать потенциально опасные места. Например, открытие соединение к БД является опасным местом, так как сервер может быть не доступен. Поэтому, перед открытием вы можете написать

> Открываю соединение к БД

,а после успешного открытия

> "Соединение успешно открыто"

Тем самым вы найдете место, где программа вылетела, если нету второго парного сообщения.

2. `Exception` внутри себя содержит стек-вызовов. Если есть отладочный файл, то там даже будет написана строчка кода, где был вылет. Сейчас вы пишите просто Message, а он, на сколько я знаю, упрощен. Пишите `Exception.ToString()` .

Comment: насчет Log4net спасибо, посмотрю. Просто обычно когда приложение вылетает с ошибкой по описанию не всегда понятно когда оно произошло. И приходится открывать IDE и с f10 проходить весь код. Может есть какая идея как в ошибке указать номер строки в которой произошел код?

Comment: Exception содержит стек вызовов и там, если есть спец. файл пишется строчка, где произошло исключение.

Comment: И если вам нужно узнать место возникновения ошибки, как альтернатива- это логировать все критические области. Например, перед соединение с БД пишете "Получаю соединение к БД", а после получения пишете "Получил соединение и открыл". При возникновении ошибки, вы сразу увидите в логе, место вылета и по отладочному сообщению найдете место.